# Pathfinding Python Algorithm Backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

Given a matrix like `board` I want to find the path that allows me to find more number `1's`, knowing that I can only go up `(n+1)` and right `(m+1)`. I'm trying to use a backtracking solution, and I managed to know how many `1's` I can find on the best path but I'm having trouble figuring out how to print the coordinates of the best path.

```
board=[[0,0,0,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,1,0,1],
       [0,0,1,0,0,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1,0]]

def findPath(board,n,m):
    noo=0
    if board[n][m]>0:
        noo+=1
    if n==len(board)-1 and m==len(board[0])-1:
        return noo
    if n==len(board)-1:
        noo+=findPath(board,n,m+1)
    elif m==len(board[0])-1:
        noo+=findPath(board,n+1,m)
    else:
        noo+=max(findPath(board,n,m+1),findPath(board,n+1,m))
    return noo

print(findPath(board,0,0))
```

How or where should I implement the `print(n,m)` to print the coordinates of every grid of the best path

**EDITED**

Came up with this solution instead

```
def path(board,x,y,xl,yl,sol,index,paths):
    sol.append([x,y])
    solaux=sol
    if x==0 and y==0:
        pass
    if board[x][y]>0:
        sol[0]+=1
    if x==xl-1 and y==yl-1:
        paths.append(sol)
        print(sol)
        return paths
    if x==xl-1:
        path(board,x,y+1,len(board),len(board[0]),sol,index,paths)
    elif y==yl-1:
        path(board,x+1,y,len(board),len(board[0]),sol,index,paths)
    else:
        index= len(sol)
        auxnoo= sol[0]
        path(board,x,y+1,len(board),len(board[0]),sol,index,paths)
        sol = sol[0:index]
        sol[0]=auxnoo
        path(board,x+1,y,len(board),len(board[0]),sol,index,paths)
    return paths
```

Comment: The editing of obvious spelling and grammar/punctuation mistakes is intended to make your question easier to read and easier to find by search. Please don't undo the work of members who are actively trying to help you and others by editing your question in a constructive fashion

Comment: my bad probably clicked the wrong button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, your implementation is very inefficient, because you do `findPath` for a single cell many times. For example, if you have 2x2 grid, cell *(1, 1)* would be visited two times:

```
(1, 0) -- path 2 --> (1, 1)
   ^                   ^
   | path 2            | path 1
   |                   |
(0, 0) -- path 1 --> (0, 1)
```

So let's memorise `noo` value for each cell:

```py
# noo[i][j] == None value means value for cell wasn't calculated before.
# Otherwise noo[i][j] it means calculated answer for cell.
noo=[[None for i in range W] for j in range H]

def findPath(board,n,m):
    if noo[n][m] is not None:
        return noo[n][m]
    noo[n][m] = board[n][m]
    if n==len(board)-1 and m==len(board[0])-1:
        return noo[n][m]
    if n==len(board)-1:
        noo[n][m]+=findPath(board,n,m+1)
    elif m==len(board[0])-1:
        noo[n][m]+=findPath(board,n+1,m)
    else:
        noo[n][m]+=max(findPath(board,n,m+1),findPath(board,n+1,m))
    return noo[n][m]

print(findPath(board,0,0))
```

> How or where should I implement the print(n,m) to print the coordinates of every grid of the best path

At second, there's no easy way to put `print(n,m)` in the given code, because for a given cell we don't know does it belong to any optimal path or not. We'll know it for sure only when we go back to cell *(0, 0)*.

But now we have 2d array `noo`: if `noo[i][j]` contains value `x`, then optimal will be direction with located relative to cell *(i, j)* to the next right or up cell *(i1, j1)* with `noo[i1][j1] >= x - 1` (`noo[i1][j1]` can be equal to `x` if `board[i][j] == 0` or `x - 1` if `board[i][j] == 1`).  Let's implement optimal path printer:

```py
def printOptimalPath(n, m):
    print(n, m)
    if n < len(board)-1 and noo[n + 1][m] == noo[n][m] - board[n][m]:
        printOptimalPath(n + 1, m)
    elif m < len(board[0])-1 and noo[n][m + 1] == noo[n][m] - board[n][m]:
        printOptimalPath(n, m + 1)

# Usage
printOptimalPath(0, 0)
```

Note, that if both `noo[n+1][m]` and `noo[n][m+1]` satisfy conditions described above it means that there is more than one optimal path and you can choose any direction.